# Are you using a POS system hooked up to a Civi instance?

Tags: civicontribute, contributions

I'm wondering if anyone is using a Point of Sale (POS) system, like Square for example, that is hooked up to a Civi instance? If so, what system are you using?

The outcome we want is to process in-person credit/debit card contributions through Civi without having people burdened to enter all 16 digits of their card number. If you or someone you know has more info about this, I would be interested, thanks!

Comment: this is not a helpful comment, but just to note that we found using Nomod with Stripe was great as it meant any phone could be used as the POS device. this was for a business that did not use Civi. But since it pushes data to Stripe it may then be possible to pull that data back in to Civi but i have no idea how much effort that would involve and may miss crucial info that you are wanting to push in to civi

Comment: Could you describe your use case? Why would you choose a full POS for example versus a store on your CMS?

What kind of features would you be needing?

Comment: Sounds like they want to be able to swipe cards when doing in-person contributions. A store wouldn't be helpful for that since it's contributions, and not purchases.

Comment: Yes, thanks, we want to be able to swipe cards when receiving an in-person contribution. Based on our past experience, Square does not allow us to collect a lot of the information we need about our donors (like name and email). Ideally we could swipe a person's card and it would autopopulate those fields of a CiviContribute form, the donor could complete the rest, and it could be integrated into the rest of our contribution accounting system. We do use Stripe as our payment processor.